# Synced Folder Error with Docker Provider on Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to automate the building of a Docker image via the docker provider in vagrant.

My directory looks like this:

```
Dockerfile external .vagrant Vagrantfile
```

The relevant parts of my Dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Austin Lopez <austinhlopez@gmail.com>

...

RUN sudo mv /tmp/external/{my_file}.tar .
RUN sudo tar xvf {my_file}.tar
```

My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-                                                                                                                                                                                         
# vi: set ft=ruby :                                                                                                                                                                                          
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder "./external", "/tmp/external"

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.build_dir = "."
    d.force_host_vm = true
  end
end
```

When I run 'vagrant up --provider=docker' I see the following lines:

```
==>default: Syncing folders to the host VM...
   default: Rsyncing folder: ./external => /var/lib/docker/docker_143...
```

In my docker file I try to access a synced file in the /tmp/external directory and I get the following error:

```
cannot stat 'tmp/external/{my_file}': no such file or directory.
```

How do I sync folders using the Docker Provider? I'm thinking that the Dockerfile is being run prior to building the Dockerfile, but I'm not sure. I also looked into Docker Volumes as a potential solution but I think that's for mounting folders from within the VM, not from the host machine.

Comment: Do you have rsync on your host machine?

Comment: I have rsync and have successfully synced folders when not using the docker provider. Also, the error occurs during the automatic docker build, which I initiate using the command 'vagrant up --provider=docker'.

Comment: Oh, it's failing to build the docker image because it needs something in the synced folder? I think the synced folder is only available to the docker container once it's been built unless I've missed something. In this case the reference in your Dockerfile should refer to `./external/` instead of `/tmp/external/`

Comment: Swapping the reference to ./external yields the same error.  To ask a follow up question: has anyone using the docker provider successfully referenced a file in a synced folder from within the Dockerfile?

Comment: Can you also post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Added the dockerfile above. I'm finding it a little odd that the folder is synced to the host VM to that /var/lib/docker/docker_143... location instead of to /tmp/external. Why does that folder sync to /var/lib/docker instead of directly to the host VM?

Answer (score 0):

The synced folder is available to the Docker container after the image is built.

Until then, Vagrant simply builds your Docker image from the Dockerfile as normal so references in your Dockerfile should reference the host instead of trying to reference the shared folder as presenter to the container.

Comment: This may work when you're running the docker provider as a virtual environment but for compatibility purposes I'm forcing the host VM to boot. The host directory doesn't appear to be available in my case.